# How could I play sound effect on add to cart button in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a sound effect to add to cart button in WooCommerce. How could I do this? I have made a sound tag and put it with the below code on `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`, but it just works on product pages. While we are in the main page the effect won't play.

```
    <button type="submit"  onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
```

Comment: Is there any element with the ID `sound1` on your overview page? Is there any error message given in your browser's console?

Comment: yes i said that and it is working on single product pages but how could i add this effect to main page or shop page????

Comment: you have changed the cart button for single-product views only - you might want to create a template for the loop cart as well.., `plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php.`